# Looping through a decoded JSON of nested elements to construct a set of requests

Tags: json, lua

I’ve read various SO posts relating to decoding JSON content, but as yet none of them seem to cover my situation.

I’m making an api call to a service that returns the following json structure, static version provided below:

```
local jsonstatic = [[
{
    "probe_no": 2,
    "probe_list":[
        {
            "probe_id": 1,
            "probe_type": 0,
            "sensor_name": ["Int. Temp1",null],
            "unit_type": [2,16],
            "alert_type": [2,3],
            "warn_range": [[18.00,37.00],[50.00,0.00]],
            "down_range": [[15.00,41.00],[60.00,0.00]],
            "alert_setting": [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
            "output": [null,null],
            "output_state": [0,0],
            "default_state": [null,null]
            
        },
        {
            "probe_id": 2,
            "probe_type": 1,
            "sensor_name": ["Ext. Temp1","Humidity1","Dew Point1"],
            "unit_type": [2,4,2],
            "alert_type": [2,2,2],
            "warn_range": [[18.00,25.00],[45.00,65.00],[18.00,25.00]],
            "down_range": [[15.00,29.00],[40.00,70.00],[15.00,29.00]],
            "alert_setting": [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
            "output": [null,null,null],
            "output_state": [0,0,0],
            "default_state": [null,null,null]
        },
        {
            "probe_id": 3,
            "probe_type": 99,
            "sensor_name": [null],
            "unit_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "alert_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "warn_range": [0,0],
            "down_range": [0,0],
            "alert_setting": [0],
            "output": [null],
            "output_state": [null],
            "default_state": [null]
        },
        {
            "probe_id": 4,
            "probe_type": 99,
            "sensor_name": [null],
            "unit_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "alert_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "warn_range": [0,0],
            "down_range": [0,0],
            "alert_setting": [0],
            "output": [null],
            "output_state": [null],
            "default_state": [null]
        },
        {
            "probe_id": 5,
            "probe_type": 99,
            "sensor_name": [null],
            "unit_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "alert_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "warn_range": [0,0],
            "down_range": [0,0],
            "alert_setting": [0],
            "output": [null],
            "output_state": [null],
            "default_state": [null]
        },
        {
            "probe_id": 6,
            "probe_type": 99,
            "sensor_name": [null],
            "unit_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "alert_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "warn_range": [0,0],
            "down_range": [0,0],
            "alert_setting": [0],
            "output": [null],
            "output_state": [null],
            "default_state": [null]
        },
        {
            "probe_id": 7,
            "probe_type": 99,
            "sensor_name": [null],
            "unit_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "alert_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "warn_range": [0,0],
            "down_range": [0,0],
            "alert_setting": [0],
            "output": [null],
            "output_state": [null],
            "default_state": [null]
        },
        {
            "probe_id": 8,
            "probe_type": 99,
            "sensor_name": [null],
            "unit_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "alert_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "warn_range": [0,0],
            "down_range": [0,0],
            "alert_setting": [0],
            "output": [null],
            "output_state": [null],
            "default_state": [null]
        },
        {
            "probe_id": 9,
            "probe_type": 99,
            "sensor_name": [null],
            "unit_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "alert_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "warn_range": [0,0],
            "down_range": [0,0],
            "alert_setting": [0],
            "output": [null],
            "output_state": [null],
            "default_state": [null]
        },
        {
            "probe_id": 10,
            "probe_type": 99,
            "sensor_name": [null],
            "unit_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "alert_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "warn_range": [0,0],
            "down_range": [0,0],
            "alert_setting": [0],
            "output": [null],
            "output_state": [null],
            "default_state": [null]
        },
        {
            "probe_id": 11,
            "probe_type": 99,
            "sensor_name": [null],
            "unit_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "alert_type": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            "warn_range": [0,0],
            "down_range": [0,0],
            "alert_setting": [0],
            "output": [null],
            "output_state": [null],
            "default_state": [null]
        }
    ]
    }
]]
```

I can retrieve specific values using the following:

```
local json = require("dkjson")
local d = json.decode(jsonstatic)
print(d.probe_list[1].probe_id) -- 1
print(d.probe_list[1].sensor_name[1]) -- "Int. Temp1"
print(d.probe_list[1].warn_range[1][1]) -- 18
print(d.probe_list[1].warn_range[1][2])-- 37
print(d.probe_list[1].probe_type)-- 0
```

But what I need to do is loop through that json to extract and process a selection of variables within each section of that JSON ?

So far I’ve made god-knows-how-many-attempts over the last few days at this, and while I can loop through to extract some of the higher level values in that JSON, but when it comes to the nested elements I end up with a reduced list (sharing one example below):

```
for k, v in pairs(d.probe_list) do
    for k1, v1 in pairs(v) do
    --print(k,k1, v1)
        if type(v1) == "table" then
            for k2, v2 in pairs (v1) do  
            --  print (k, k1, v1, k2, v2) 
                    if type(v2) == "table" then
                        for k3, v3 in pairs (v2) do  
                            print (k, v, k1, v1, k2, v2, k3, v3)
                        end
                    end 
            end
        end
    end
end
```

How can I get all values to play out on one line/row. Is it even possible to extract such a selection of values all together via a loop?

To avoid complicating matters by trying to explain the eventual command I need to populate with these values, to keep it simple and help me learn, let’s say I wanted to loop through the json and build a sentence out of each sensor/section?

How would I do something like the following..

```
"The probe No is “ .. ProbeNo .. “ which is called “ .. probe name .. ", which is set to warn you when it’s value is recorded below  " .. warn1 .. " or above " .. warn2 .. " etc.”
```

Please note:  I ideally need the sensor name of each element to act as the unique identifier, so is it possible to construct a sentence for each one? Which means for some it has 3 sensors in one section.

### Update

I think I can construct something workable using the following logic/approach, but it’s likely to be quite long - hence the reason for this post is to learn if it’s possible to do something more dynamic using the decoded json and a loop

```
function findprode(probename)
    if d.probe_list[1].sensor_name[1] == probename then
    print("found " ..probename.. ", its probe ID = ".. d.probe_list[1].probe_id .. " it's warning values are lower than " ..d.probe_list[1].warn_range[1][1].. " or higher than " ..d.probe_list[1].warn_range[1][2])
    elseif d.probe_list[2].sensor_name[1] == probename then
    print("found " ..probename.. ", its probe ID = ".. d.probe_list[2].probe_id.. " it's warning values are lower than " ..d.probe_list[2].warn_range[1][1].. " or higher than " ..d.probe_list[2].warn_range[1][2])
    elseif d.probe_list[3].sensor_name[1] == probename then
    print("found " ..probename.. ", its probe ID = ".. d.probe_list[3].probe_id.. " it's warning values are lower than " ..d.probe_list[3].warn_range[1][1].. " or higher than " ..d.probe_list[3].warn_range[1][2])
    elseif d.probe_list[4].sensor_name[1] == probename then
    print("found " ..probename.. ", its probe ID = ".. d.probe_list[4].probe_id.. " it's warning values are lower than " ..d.probe_list[4].warn_range[1][1].. " or higher than " ..d.probe_list[4].warn_range[1][2])
    else
    print(probename.. " NOT FOUND")
    end
end
findprode("Int. Temp1")
```

Comment: seems like you aren't checking that `v1` is a table in your example code, and `v1` is not always a table so you will get an error. You didn't specify what error you got from that attempt, was it `bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got number)`? if so just set that inner most loop in an if statement using `type(v1) == "table"` as the condition.

Comment: Thanks @Nifim, i have updated the question above to factor in the == “table” element, which I had  tried, but it (obviously) only reduced the content returned. I ideally need the loop to list by sensor name,  all it’s associated variables from the JSON.

Comment: then why don't you just do `for k, v in pairs(d.probe_list) do; for k2, v2 in pairs(v.sensor_name) do; print(k, k2, v2) end end`?